# What are the properties of the electromagnetic radiation from a magnetron?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, microwaves, photon-emission

There are different modes of EM radiation. A bulb emits photons in a wide range of wavelengths and without polarisation. Radio waves are polarized modulated radiation.

What is about the radiation from a [magnetron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavity_magnetron)? Is the microwave radiation monochromatic, is it polarized, is it a modulated radiation and related to the cavities of the magnetron?

Edit: The properties "monochromatic", "polarised", "modulated" are examples only. I'm interested in first line about does a modulation takes place.

Comment: I would say that depends on how you design your magnetron and in which regime you operate it, which, in the end, is more of an engineering question. The answer also depends on the engineering criteria you apply to terms like "monochromatic". A magnetron, by itself, is not a particularly good oscillator, so for most technical applications (like in communications) an engineer would stay away from treating its output as monochromatic. Like with any other type of oscillator one can clean it up, of course, and then it may be monochromatic (and polarized) enough for many applications.

Comment: @CuriousOne The monochromatism is not the point. I'm curious about is it a modulated radiation or not.

Comment: Engineers speak of modulation and noise spectra in detail, while physicists talk about monochromatic radiation mostly crudely. It seems to me that this question may receive more detailed answers about the design of clean magnetron oscillators than it will here.

Comment: As an aside, I see no reason why generic radio waves are polarized (or necessarily modulated if you just send the carrier). So, we seem to have a clash, or misunderstanding, about 'monochromatic' and 'modulated' (as well as, possibly, 'polarized'). But, a well engineered magnetron+output waveguide will have some reasonable band width, and would likely have one cavity mode as the desired output.